# Property in Component State not updating quick enough

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures

I'm trying to display text when I hover over an icon, but if you hover the icons quickly it'll get stuck on displaying the text instead of displaying the icon (default state)

ex: https://giphy.com/gifs/UsS4JcRJGV5qfCI5VI

Skills Component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { UserIcon } from './AboutBtnStyling';
import IconText from '../../../IconText';

const AboutBtn = () => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  const onHover = () => {
    setHover(true)
  }

  const onLeave = () => {
    setHover(false)
  }

  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={onHover} onMouseLeave={onLeave} role="button">
      {hover ? <IconText text="ABOUT" /> : <UserIcon /> }
    </div>
  )
}

export default AboutBtn;
```

Then I hoped converting it to a class component would help, bc of stale closure problem associate with useState hook

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SkillIcon } from './SkillsBtnStyling';
import IconText from '../../../IconText';

class SkillsBtn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this. state = { hover: false }
  }

  onHover = () => {
    this.setState({ hover: true })
  }

  onLeave = () => {
    this.setState({ hover: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onMouseEnter={this.onHover} onMouseLeave={this.onLeave} role="button">
      {this.state.hover ? <IconText text="SKILLS" /> : <SkillIcon /> }
    </div>
    )
  }

}

export default SkillsBtn;
```

Would greatly appreciate any insight! I really want to solve this problem, instead of resorting to achieving this effect using CSS

Comment: Browser doesn't  controll every pixel on mouse events. Some of them can be missed. CSS :hover and couple of images would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

An important aspect of useState is that it is asynchronous. I believe this is causing your code to act a bit buggy. I would add more decisiveness to your setState calls and set it (true/false) based on mouse position rather than toggle.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SkillsButton } from './SkillsBtnElements'

const SkillsBtn = () => {
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
const onHover = () => {
    setHover(!hover)
}

return (
    <div onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)} onMouseLeave={() =>                                        
        setHover(false)} role="button" tabIndex='-3' >
        { hover ? "SKILLS" : <SkillsButton /> }
    </div>
 )
}

export default SkillsBtn;
```

Comment: Sorry, I shared an old snippet. I have now updated the code snippet, but the buggy behavior still exists